# Bound the norm of sum of random vector that generated from standard basis

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, measure-concentration

I have a question like this:
Consider $N$ samples $X_1, X_2, ..., X_N$ that uniformly random generated from standard basis $\{e_i, i=1,2,...,d\}$, i.e. $(1,0,0,\cdots,0),(0,1,0,\cdots,0),(0,0,1,0,\cdots,0),\cdots,(0,0,0,\cdots,1)$. Dimension $d$. My question is how can I get an upper bound on $\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|$. I know $\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|=\frac{N}{\sqrt{d}}$. In other word, what concentration inequality should I use to get something like
$$
P(|\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|-\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\||>\epsilon)\leq \delta
$$

so that I can rewrite $\epsilon$ as a form contains $\delta, d, N $ and upper bound $\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|$ with probability $1-\delta$.

Thanks!

Comment: The equality $\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|=\frac{N}{\sqrt{d}}$ does not hold even for $N=1$ and $d\ge2$. Actually, $\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|\ge\|\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\|=\frac{N}{\sqrt{d}}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and point this out. In this situation, how can I bound the expectation of the norm of sum of X_i? Using reverse Jensen or consider it as bounding the norm of sum of random matrices?

Comment: I explained how to bound it from below. To bound it from above, you can use the inequality $EV\le\sqrt{EV^2}$. As for the answer below, are you satisfied with it?

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n:=N$ and $V:=\|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\|$.

Using [Talagrand's concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talagrand%27s_concentration_inequality) as applied to linear functions in [Section 2.2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec13.pdf), we can get
$$P(|V-EV\,|\ge x)\le5\exp\Big(-\frac{x^2}{16n}\Big)$$
for all real $x\ge0$. One can see that this bound does not depend on $d$.

I will not provide details on this, because in this situation one can get better constants using McDiarmid's inequality, and this can be done almost immediately. Indeed, letting $g(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\|$ for $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\{e_1,\dots,e_d\}^n$, we see that $g(X_1,\dots,X_n)=V$ and [condition (18)](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/fall13/notes/concentration.pdf) holds with $c_i=\sqrt2$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.  So, by [inequalities (19)--(20) in the same lecture notes](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/fall13/notes/concentration.pdf),
$$P(|V-EV\,|\ge x)\le2\exp\Big(-\frac{x^2}{n}\Big)$$
for all real $x\ge0$.